# Qual o significado dos prefixos dos pseudo-elementos em css?

Tags: css

Qual o significado dos prefixos dos pseudo-elementos em css?
Como por exemplo - nth-child, o que significa o nth no inicio?

Comment: O `nth` significa enésimo... (acho que é assim que se escreve). Ou seja descendente n-ésimo, que depois é indicado dentro do parentesis. É isso que procuras saber?

Comment: Tem alguma fonte segura de onde isto é citado?

Comment: O mais próximo seria em espanhol (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) mas podes acreditar em mim :)

Answer (score 7):

O nth significa enésimo. Ou seja descendente n-ésimo, que depois é especificado dentro do parentesis.

Um exemplo seria:

```
span:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    background-color: lime;
}
```

Este CSS irá colorir os elementos ímpares. `2n` seria para pares.
**Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/wc2gs1g4/**

Aqui ele conta com todos os elementos que são irmãos/siblings.

Nota que usando este HTML:

```
<div> 
 <span>Colorido!</span>
 <span>Não colorido:(</span>
 <em>Não colorido:(</em>
 <span>Não colorido:(</span>
 <span>Colorido!</span>
</div>
```

Ele não aplica nada ao `<em>` mas conta com ele! Ou seja o `nth` refere-se a enésimo descendente/sibling, e não à tag que é associada ao próprio, senão no caso em cima o terceiro `span` deveria ser colorido pois é ímpar (se tivermos em conta só os spans)

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wc2gs1g4/1/

---

#### A lêr: [MDN - nth-child() <sup>em Inglês</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: Quanto a aplicação é tranquilo, gostaria mesmo de saber o significado. Agradeço as respostas.

Answer (score 2):

Em adição a resposta do @Sergio, em inglês, números ordinais (tirando os três primeiros) são completados com `th` para dar a indicação de que são ordinais:

> First
>       Second
>       Third
>       Four**th**
>       Fif**th**
>       Six**th**
>       Seven**th**

Ou podem ser escritos como `4th, 5th, 6th`. O `nth` no caso, se refere ao numero `n`, ordinariamente falando, se referindo a posição do elemento em seu container. Em português seria algo como `xth`